# Abrir WhatsApp quando clicar no ícone

Tags: php, javascript, html, whatsapp

Alguém sabe como fazer com que ao clicar no ícone do WhatsApp em um site pelo *smartphone*, alguma função abra o aplicativo e já inicie uma conversa no número definido no *link* do site?

Imagine um ícone que diga "atendimento por WhatsApp 9988-7755" e ao clicar ali já inicie uma conversa no WhatsApp direto nesse número xxxx-xxxx? Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="intent://send/NUMERO_TELEFONE#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">
<img src="img/whatspng.png"></a>
```

Comment: Funciona, mas somente no Android. Alguma ideia para outras plataformas?

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um ícone e no click do ícone este link com o numero desejado.

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+5519999999999